# Gimp - fast switching to eraser

Tags: gimp

I've been searching for this but all I find are annoying tutorials on how to click the eraser button.

Whenever I switch to the eraser it keeps the tool size I was using for the pencil, I'd really like it if it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck brush option in **Edit- Preferences - Tool options- Paint options shared between tools**

Comment: Thanks, is there a list any resource you can recommend for "learning Gimp but not being really slow" - because the tutorials and stuff are painfully slow.

Comment: As per my opinion, if you want to learn GIMP in detail, reading books might help you (although it is even more time consuming than tutorials)One such book I found useful is 'Beginning GIMP' by Akkana Peck. For tricks you might look at GIMP video tutorials.

Comment: The GIMP user manual is a recommended reading: http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/ - some people even expect you to be reading it when they give you advice.